# Convert base64 api response to .apk file and download it

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, base64

I am working with react and have a problem -> When a user clicks a button, the API is called which returns a base64. Is it possible to somehow convert that base64 to .apk file and then download it? My current onClick function looks like this:

```
const downloadApp = async() => {
    await userService.downloadMobileApp()
    .then(response=> {
      console.log("response: ",response);
      const linkSource = `data:application/apk;base64,${response.data}`;
      const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      const fileName = 'randomAppName.apk';
      downloadLink.href = linkSource;
      downloadLink.download = fileName;
      console.log("downloadLink: ",downloadLink)
      downloadLink.click();})
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("error: ",error)
    })
  }
```

I use this kind of code to convert and download .pdf files (using pdf instead of apk in '...:application/apk;base64...', but with .apk it isn't working. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the response is a base64 string and it is an apk file that is encoded than you can just decode the base64 to obtain the bytes of that apk file. So you have the file then already. There is nothing more to download then. Dont understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use **atob()** method to decode the data string then create a **Blob** object from that data

```js
const data = atob(response.data);
const blob = new Blob([decodedData], { type: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive' });
const linkSource = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
...
```